# select in sub query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT LOTTOID,
      CASE WHEN VAL0 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL1 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL2 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL3 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL4 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN VAL5 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS totalValues
INTO #tempWinners
FROM tblLotto
```

But I get the following error on line2:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

The `tblDraw` table looks like this:

```
LOTTOID VAL0    VAL1    VAL2    VAL3    VAL4    VAL5    DRAWDATE
    3    7       13      15      17      21      43     2013-06-23 10:56:08.927
```

Basically what im trying to do is use SQL to work out if someone has matching lotto numbers.

The tblDraw table is the draw (obviously). I know i can do a check like this:

`SELECT VAL0 FROM tblLotto WHERE IN (SELECT VAL0 FROM tblDraw)`

but the val0 in tblLotto wont always match the val0 column in the draw as potentially "7" may be in the column `val4` Therefore i need to do a check for all columns...

Comment: Please post your table structures and sample data

Comment: updated please check....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner select in

```
  CASE WHEN VAL0 IN (SELECT * FROM tblDraw) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

needs to return exactly one column. Currently it is returning all column of `dbo.tblDraw`.

The only time when you can use a `SELECT * FROM` in a sub-query is when the sub-query is an `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM...)` query.

---

UPDATE:

Your problem is caused by your table design. If you have a table for the draw event and another table that contains one row per picked number and a similar layout on the customer side, you are following 3rd normal form and the query becomes a lot simpler. However let's assume you can't change the table schema. I am also assuming that you are on SQL 2008 or later as my solution won't work on 2005 or earlier.

To get the result you are looking for you basically need to unpivot the draw values as well as the customer selection values. Than you can just join the to result sets and count how many rows you get back. Assuming all values are unique (usually the case in a lottery) this will give you the number of correct selections the customer did against the lottery draw.

I have posted an example solution below. Don't be shocked by all the code. most of that is to create the table and put some random values into them. Only the query after the **Query 1** headline is what you are looking for.

I took the liberty change the names when I created the objects. I also changed the numbers around a little to make it more likely for matches to happen. The lottery in my examples is a 6 out of 15 lottery. But that is only relevant for the example data creation, not for the final query.

The query first joins the dbo.LottoDraws table against the dbo.CustomerSelections table. then id does a cross apply to a subquery. That subquery uses the `VALUE` operator to unpivot the values first of the customer's selections and then of the LotteryDraws. It then joins those two result sets together and counts the matches.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71783/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LottoDraws(
  draw_date DATE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  draw1 INT,
  draw2 INT,
  draw3 INT,
  draw4 INT,
  draw5 INT,
  draw6 INT
);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerSelections(
  customer_id INT,-- REFERENCES Customer(customer_id)
  draw_date DATE,
  val1 INT,
  val2 INT,
  val3 INT,
  val4 INT,
  val5 INT,
  val6 INT,
  CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerPicks PRIMARY KEY (customer_id,draw_date)
);

GO
DELETE FROM dbo.LottoDraws;
DELETE FROM dbo.CustomerSelections;


INSERT INTO dbo.LottoDraws(draw_date,draw1,draw2,draw3,draw4,draw5,draw6)
SELECT CAST(dates.d AS DATE) AS draw_date,X4.*
FROM
(VALUES('2013-01-01'),('2013-02-02'),('2013-03-03'),('2013-04-04'),('2013-05-05'))dates(d)
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'val'+LTRIM(STR(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT val)))) pick, val
FROM(
SELECT TOP(6) val
FROM(SELECT TOP(15) ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))*SIGN(LEN(dates.d)) val 
     FROM sys.columns a,sys.columns b,sys.columns c,sys.columns d)X1
ORDER BY NEWID()
)X2
)X3
PIVOT(MAX(val) FOR pick IN([val1],[val2],[val3],[val4],[val5],[val6]))P
)X4
;

INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerSelections(customer_id,draw_date,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6)
SELECT customers.customer_id,CAST(dates.d AS DATE) AS draw_date,X4.*
FROM
(VALUES(111),(222),(333),(444))customers(customer_id)
CROSS JOIN
(VALUES('2013-01-01'),('2013-02-02'),('2013-03-03'),('2013-04-04'),('2013-05-05'))dates(d)
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'val'+LTRIM(STR(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT val)))) pick, val
FROM(
SELECT TOP(6) val
FROM(SELECT TOP(15) ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))*SIGN(customers.customer_id+LEN(dates.d)) val 
     FROM sys.columns a,sys.columns b,sys.columns c,sys.columns d)X1
ORDER BY NEWID()
)X2
)X3
PIVOT(MAX(val) FOR pick IN([val1],[val2],[val3],[val4],[val5],[val6]))P
)X4
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LottoDraws ld
JOIN dbo.CustomerSelections cs
ON ld.draw_date = cs.draw_date
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT COUNT(1) correct_count
  FROM (VALUES(cs.val1),(cs.val2),(cs.val3),(cs.val4),(cs.val5),(cs.val6))csv(val)
  JOIN (VALUES(ld.draw1),(ld.draw2),(ld.draw3),(ld.draw4),(ld.draw5),(ld.draw6))ldd(draw)
  ON csv.val = ldd.draw
)CC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71783/1/0)**:

```
|  DRAW_DATE | DRAW1 | DRAW2 | DRAW3 | DRAW4 | DRAW5 | DRAW6 | CUSTOMER_ID | VAL1 | VAL2 | VAL3 | VAL4 | VAL5 | VAL6 | CORRECT_COUNT |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-01-01 |     2 |     3 |     4 |     5 |     8 |    12 |         111 |    3 |    6 |    9 |   11 |   14 |   15 |             1 |
| 2013-02-02 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    12 |    14 |         111 |    1 |    2 |    3 |   10 |   11 |   14 |             3 |
| 2013-03-03 |     5 |     6 |     8 |    10 |    11 |    14 |         111 |    2 |    3 |    6 |   13 |   14 |   15 |             2 |
| 2013-04-04 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    10 |    12 |         111 |    3 |    5 |    6 |    7 |   12 |   15 |             4 |
| 2013-05-05 |     3 |     6 |     7 |    10 |    11 |    12 |         111 |    1 |    4 |    6 |    7 |    9 |   11 |             3 |
| 2013-01-01 |     2 |     3 |     4 |     5 |     8 |    12 |         222 |    3 |    6 |    8 |    9 |   11 |   14 |             2 |
| 2013-02-02 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    12 |    14 |         222 |    5 |    7 |   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |             3 |
| 2013-03-03 |     5 |     6 |     8 |    10 |    11 |    14 |         222 |    2 |    6 |    8 |   10 |   13 |   14 |             4 |
| 2013-04-04 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    10 |    12 |         222 |    4 |    7 |    8 |   11 |   12 |   15 |             1 |
| 2013-05-05 |     3 |     6 |     7 |    10 |    11 |    12 |         222 |    1 |    2 |    4 |    5 |   11 |   14 |             1 |
| 2013-01-01 |     2 |     3 |     4 |     5 |     8 |    12 |         333 |    3 |    7 |    8 |   10 |   14 |   15 |             2 |
| 2013-02-02 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    12 |    14 |         333 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    7 |    8 |   10 |             2 |
| 2013-03-03 |     5 |     6 |     8 |    10 |    11 |    14 |         333 |    5 |    6 |    7 |   11 |   12 |   14 |             4 |
| 2013-04-04 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    10 |    12 |         333 |    1 |    8 |   11 |   12 |   14 |   15 |             1 |
| 2013-05-05 |     3 |     6 |     7 |    10 |    11 |    12 |         333 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    8 |   10 |   13 |             2 |
| 2013-01-01 |     2 |     3 |     4 |     5 |     8 |    12 |         444 |    2 |    8 |   10 |   11 |   13 |   14 |             2 |
| 2013-02-02 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    12 |    14 |         444 |    4 |    6 |    7 |    9 |   10 |   13 |             1 |
| 2013-03-03 |     5 |     6 |     8 |    10 |    11 |    14 |         444 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    6 |   11 |   15 |             2 |
| 2013-04-04 |     2 |     3 |     5 |     6 |    10 |    12 |         444 |    2 |    4 |    7 |    8 |   12 |   14 |             2 |
| 2013-05-05 |     3 |     6 |     7 |    10 |    11 |    12 |         444 |    4 |    7 |   11 |   13 |   14 |   15 |             2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

VAL0, VAL1.... are looking for a single column in the sub query. instead of `select * from tblDraw`, try returning a unique column.